# C# URL query string parameters not parsing correctly in FireFox or Chrome

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, url

I have a function in my code to open various reports in SSRS, which may or may not need to accept a parameter(s). I'm passing the URL and parameters as follows:

```
var reportUrl = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ReportServerUrl"];
        var reportPathComponents = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ReportPath"].Split(';');
        var reportPath = string.Join("&", reportPathComponents);

        return reportUrl + string.Format(reportPath, start.ToShortDateString(), end.ToShortDateString());
```

Possible inputs are:

reportUrl = "http://ssrs14devreports..."
ReportPath = "Report;rs:Command=Render;start={0};end={1}"

This works just fine in IE 11 but in the latest Chrome and FireFox browsers it encodes the "&" as "&-amp;". Please excuse the - in "&-amp;".

Answer (score 1):

Not sure that it's the problem, but I would not concatenate two urls with the "+" sign, use

```
Uri uri = new Uri(new Uri(reportUrl), reportPath);
```

instead...

Check the url and verify that you do not have two // instead of one...

Comment: I checked the url and it does have two //. And as I said it does work in IE 11. Just now Chrome or FireFox.

Comment: You should only have one slash. Using `Uri` as suggested should fix the problem...